# Minimum Of An Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm confused as to what I should return from:

```
public static double min(double[] array) {
    double[] tenDoubles = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter " + tenDoubles.length + " numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tenDoubles.length; i++){
        tenDoubles[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < tenDoubles.length; j++) {
        double currentMin = tenDoubles[j];
        double currentMinIndex = j;
        for (int k = j; k < tenDoubles.length; k++) {
            if (currentMin > tenDoubles[k]) {
                currentMin = tenDoubles[k];
                currentMinIndex = k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I return a value from this method and print out the minimum double the user inputs?

Comment: What is the purpose of `for (int j = 0; j < tenDoubles.length; j++) {` loop? What would happen if you would replace `j` with `0` value inside of it?

Answer (score 2):

**By using java api you can find minimum number**
To find minimun convert our array `tenDoubles` to `List` and then find the minimum using `Collections.min()` method.

**In your code I have done modification to resolve issue**
I have modified your code, you are taking input at two places from user.
1. In `min()` method you are taking input using scanner.
2. you are not using `double[] array` passed as parameter to `min()` method.

Pass your array as parameter to `min()` method It will find out minimum value ans pass result.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] tenDoubles = new double[10];
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter " + tenDoubles.length + " numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < tenDoubles.length; i++){
            tenDoubles[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println(min(tenDoubles));
    }

    public static double min(double[] tenDoubles) {

        double currentMin=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = 0; j < tenDoubles.length; j++) {
            if (tenDoubles[j]< currentMin) {
                currentMin = tenDoubles[j];
            }
        }
        return currentMin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example needs restructuring.  Read in your values into an array first and then pass this array as a parameter to your min function.  To return the minimum, add

```
return currentMinIndex;
```

Finally use System.out.println to print the value returned.

Your min function will then look like

```
public static double min(double[] array) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        double currentMin = array[j];
        double currentMinIndex = j;
        for (int k = j; k < array.length; k++) {
            if (currentMin > array[k]) {
                currentMin = array[k];
                currentMinIndex = k;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentMinIndex;
}
```

though it is not necessary to go through the array twice.

Comment: Because the original poster did.  I did note that it was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Improved code:

```
public static double min() {
  double[] tenDoubles = new double[10];// = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter " + tenDoubles.length + " numbers: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < tenDoubles.length; i++){
      tenDoubles[i] = input.nextDouble();
}

  double currentMin = tenDoubles[0];
  for (int j = 1; j < tenDoubles.length; j++) {
       if (currentMin > tenDoubles[j]) {
           currentMin = tenDoubles[j];
       }        
  }

  return currentMin;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the min value (which you are doing) and have it compared to each other element in the array. If the next element is less, then you change out the values.

```
// This will hold what the minimum value is
double currentMin = 0;

// The current value from the tenDoubles array
double currentValue;

// loop through each element of the array
for (int j = 0; j < tenDoubles.length; j++) {
    // get the current value from the array
    currentValue = tenDoubles[j];

    // if this is the first element, then just set the minimum to this value
    if (j ==0) {
        // Set the value as the minimum
        currentMin = currentValue;
    }else {
        // if the current value is less that what is already saved as the minimum,
        // set it as the new minimum
        if (currentValue < currentMin) {
            currentMin = currentValue;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Minimum value: " + currentMin);

return currentMin;
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't have to use the for-loops, you can shorten this up a lot by just doing this:

```
public static double min(double[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);

    return array[0];
}
```

Comment: Closing Scanner which uses `System.in` is rarely good idea unless we are doing it right before application will be closed.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? It's a potential resource leak. Or are you referring to *where* I suggested to close it?

Comment: Many question on SO describes problems where someone created Scanner handling data from `System.in` in method and closed it inside this method. Idea seemed valid since compiler suggested that scanner should be closed, but since it also closed `System.in` this method could be used only once. That is why I added "unless we are doing it right before application will be closed".

Comment: Good to know! Thanks :-) I removed that comment

Comment: So should I put the SOP outside of the min method, and instead into the main method? Then from there print what is returned?

Comment: You don't even need the SOP. I just added that to the code so you could see the value that will be returned :-) But yes, you can just print what you get returned from here instead. it would be the same thing